# Sequence points missing in some portable PDB files

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection, pdb-files, system.reflection.metadata

## Context

I'm developing a documentation generating tool for .NET libraries, which extracts types from assemblies via reflection and relevant documentation from the compile-time generated XML.

[My project for more context](https://github.com/hailstorm75/MarkDoc.Core)

## Goal

I want to extend my tool with the ability to display for each type member (method, property...) their origin in the source code - extract the source file and relevant line number.

## Current state

I've used `System.Reflection.Metadata` to load PDB files and extract the required data successfully.

```cs
using var stream = new StreamReader(pdbPath);
var provider = MetadataReaderProvider.FromPortablePdbStream(stream.BaseStream, MetadataStreamOptions.PrefetchMetadata, 0);
var reader = provider.GetMetadataReader();
var scopes = reader.MethodDebugInformation
  .Where(h => !h.IsNil)
  .Select(md => (reader.GetMethodDebugInformation(md), System.Reflection.Metadata.Ecma335.MetadataTokens.GetToken(md.ToDefinitionHandle())))
  .Where(m => !m.Item1.SequencePointsBlob.IsNil)
  .Select(m =>
  {
      return m.Item1.GetSequencePoints()
      .Select(sp =>
      {
           var document = reader.GetDocument(sp.Document);
            var name = reader.GetString(document.Name);

            return (m.Item2, sp.StartLine, name);
      })
      .OrderBy(x => x.StartLine)
      .First();
  })
  .ToArray();
```

## Issue

The issue is that the `MethodDebugInformation` `SequencePoints` are not reliably available. Some of my PDBs return nothing, others return all member sequence points.

All tested PDBs come from .NET Core/5+ projects. No .NET Framework.

## Question

What am I doing wrong? Are my PDBs compiled incorrectly? Or am I misusing the reflection library?
Thanks in advance for any tips